# What's the difference between Berberis Thunbergii cultivars 'Golden Ring' and 'Coronita'?

Tags: plant-recommendations, shrubs, variety-selection, barberry

I'm trying to distinguish between two cultivars of Berberis Thunbergii.

Two that are similar are available in my area: 'Golden Ring' and 'Coronita'.

What is the difference? What do you recommend?

Comment: Hi VividD! Would you mind adding some detail to this question? I see that you've posted other questions, but in order for people to understand, each question needs the same basic information, like where you live. (If it's helpful, you can also post a link to a previous question.) What usage are you looking for out of this plant? That can help us recommend the best cultivar for your purpose. If you can think of anything else we should know, that would be great! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difficult to find out much about Berberis 'Coronita', but this Polish site http://kurowski.pl/pl/katalog-roslin/1/1/roslina/1490,berberis-thunbergii-golden-ring lists both - according to the descriptions, B. 'Coronita' is a 'sprawling' shrub up to 1.5m, whereas B. 'Golden Ring' is described as reaching 2m, but is not similarly described as 'sprawling', from which one could deduce the latter is more upright in its growth habit. Otherwise, in appearance of the leaves, flowers and berries, they are markedly similar. The RHS website lists B. 'Golden Ring' as having a height and spread of 1 to 1.5m, which isn't terribly helpful because it disagrees with the Polish description, but that word 'sprawling' would put me off B. 'Coronita' - though it depends on where it's being planted and what purpose it's intended to serve whether that's a plus or a minus for you.

Comment: Thanks, I think I saw an adult 'Coronita' planted as decoration in the nursery that sells it (but does not sell 'Golden Ring'), I may take a pic if I happen to go there. If I remember well, it definitelly looks sprawling, atypical for berberis.

Comment: Having looked at images online, I can't honestly see much difference in growth habit either...though there is an impression that the pale edging to the leaves is slightly broader and more noticeable on 'Coronita'.  If you don't mind a more compact shrub, reaching probably a metre, Berberis 'Admiration' is a much neater grower, but I don't know if that fits the bill for what you want.

Comment: Please note that Berberis is considered an invasive in some areas. The entire genus was nearly banned in Wisconsin two years ago; they eventually banned only some older cultivars (rumors in the industry is that money changed hands. Yes, the state is that corrupt). All I know is, is that walking off-trail through wooded parks in the western part of the state can be VERY painful, thanks to bird-planted berberis.

Comment: @Jurp luckily, VividD is in Europe, where its not listed as invasive, but I'm intrigued, which variety is the biggest problem in Wisconsin?

Comment: @Jurp , in my area, berberis is even planted by government in public spaces, and I never heard anyone complaining about them here. I believe it is really small chance that a bird will bring berberis seed from here over Atlantic ocean to Wisconsin or Minesota, so don't worry. ;)

Comment: @ Bamboo - Prohibited from being brought into the state or sold in the state: Berberis vulgaris; Restricted from sale: Berberis thunbergii. Landowners are under no obligation to remove prohibited plants, however, so our invasive species laws are pretty much a joke.

Comment: @ Vivid - Didn't know you were in Europe :)  I have a Berberis story - when I was 4 years old, my father and my German great-uncle removed about 12 feet of 6 foot high berberis; I helped them by watching. About ten minutes after they started trying to dig the shrubs up, I learned how to swear in both English and German.

Comment: @Jurp never heard of B. vulgaris... will look that up. And I'm not surprised the air was blue and you learned to swear... Berberis is an absolute pig to work with - tiny little spiky thorns that stick down the side of fingernails more often than not, having somehow got through  your leather workgloves... I try never to touch it, lifting cut pieces using my secateurs or loppers. But roses are the worst, followed by pyracantha